# Open a form after clicking more cell table (jquery/php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a calendar table and i've used this script to change bgcolor (css class .clicked) value of one or more td tag.

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
        $("td#target").bind('mouseover',function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        });
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        $("td#target").unbind('mouseover');
    });

    $("td#target").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
```

Now i need that on mouseup will open a popup form, but i'm not able to do it.
Can you help me?

Example:
i'm selecting cells from 15 to 20 may, on mouse click will open a popup with a form "Compile these fields for day 15-16-17-18-19-20"

Thank you

Comment: can you post relevant html??

Answer (score 0):

You can just make divs that are positioned fixed or absolute and they will overlay the underlaying content. The overlaying div(popup) will be a normal div where you can make forms and whatever you want. Here is a quick jsfiddle I threw toghether: http://jsfiddle.net/0zvqm5nr/35/

Here is the code of the jsfiddle:

HTML

```
 <div class="calendar">
Your calendar would be here and for every entry you can generate a div 'calendar-entry' as shown in the html
<div class="calendar-entry">
    <button id="popupButton" class="calendar-entry-button">15.05.2015</button>
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>15.05.2015</h2>
        Activity: 
        <form action="somesite.php" method="post">
            <select id="activity">
                <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Select</option>
                <option>work</option>
                <option>youth leave</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="save">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="calendar-entry">
    <button id="popupButton" class="calendar-entry-button">16.05.2015</button>
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>16.05.2015</h2>
        Activity: 
        <form action="somesite.php" method="post">
            <select id="activity">
                <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Select</option>
                <option>work</option>
                <option>youth leave</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="save">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
and so on...
```

CSS

```
.calendar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}
.popup {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-entry-button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     buttons[i].onclick = function() {
         this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.display = "block";
     }    
}
```

I hope this helped.